# shopware 6 upload multiple product variation images

Tags: api, shopware

Can we upload multiple image to the variation using API. Single image upload can be possible using below code, but not sure about multiple image upload.

```
$mediaId ='random string';
$url = $images['url'];    
$mediaData = array(
    array(
        'id' => $mediaId,
        'mediaFolderId' => $mediaFolderID,
    ),
);
$mediaDataArr = array(
    'payload' => array(
        "action" => "upsert",
        "entity" => "media",
        'payload' => $mediaData,
    ),
);
$createMedia = $shopware6HelperObj->post('_action/sync', $mediaDataArr);
$urlArr = array(
    'url' => $url,
);
$parts = pathinfo($url);
$params = array(
    'extension' => $parts['extension'],
    'fileName' => $parts['filename'] . '__' . md5(time()),
);
$uploadImage = $shopware6HelperObj->post('_action/media/' . $mediaId . '/upload', $urlArr, $params);
```

Please suggest if any idea.

Answer (score 0):

I always recommend to try doing that via the Admin Panel and check the Browser's Dev Tools / Network Tab which requests are made. This can give you a good hint on how do to it programmatically.